# how do I remove CSS margins

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, web-parts

My summary-links webpart in Office 365 is having difficulty placing the groups in columns. There seems to be a wide fixed margin. I'm willing to correct it using CSS, but I can't find the offending style.

-- Image removed

Comment: I want the width of the div (column) 25% and aligned left, so that the subsequent div (columns) sit to the right of it.

Comment: you can as well give {float:left ;width: 25%;}

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: May I know the reason for unaccepting the answer? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not `margin` you are having an issue with. Looks like its `width` from your screen shot. You have given `width:25%` and the `div` tags are by default `display:block` - Try making them `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Theh `<div>`s are by default `display: block`. If you give the `div` a CSS:

```
.dfwp-column {width: 25%; display: inline-block;}
```

It would make them sit next to each other.